# Google Adsense Output

Tags: adsense

I want to Google Adsense script output code (HTML code)
I don't mean the javascript code (which google provides to users). The HTML output (you can grab it with `Firebug` or Google Developer Toolbar)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The I frame is :

```
<iframe width="120" scrolling="no" height="600" frameborder="0" vspace="0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0" src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-7051474033111975&amp;output=html&amp;h=600&amp;slotname=1193041517&amp;w=120&amp;lmt=1339606481&amp;flash=11.2.202&amp;url=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2FDocuments%2520and%2520Settings%2FLEFTERIS%2FDesktop%2Fgoogle.htm&amp;dt=1339608015911&amp;bpp=4&amp;shv=r20120606&amp;jsv=r20110914&amp;correlator=1339608016097&amp;frm=20&amp;adk=1708676694&amp;ga_vid=904765143.1337074819&amp;ga_sid=1339608016&amp;ga_hid=1901222006&amp;ga_fc=1&amp;u_tz=180&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_java=1&amp;u_h=1024&amp;u_w=1280&amp;u_ah=934&amp;u_aw=1280&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_nplug=20&amp;u_nmime=76&amp;dff=serif&amp;dfs=16&amp;adx=8&amp;ady=8&amp;biw=1244&amp;bih=293&amp;oid=3&amp;fu=0&amp;ifi=1&amp;dtd=235&amp;xpc=dCXR5D0l2L&amp;p=file%3A//" name="google_ads_frame1" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" id="google_ads_frame1" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

<style>a{color:#0000ff}body,table,div,ul,li{margin:0;padding:0}</style>

<script>(function(){window.ss=function(d,e){window.status=d;var c=document.getElementById(e);if(c){var a;a=c.href;var b=a.match("^(.*)([?|&]nm=)([^&]*)(.*)$");b?(b[3]=""+((Number(b[3])||0)+1),b[0]="",a=b.join("")):a+="&nm=1";c.href=a}return!0};})();function su(id) {var a = document.getElementById(id);var b = (new Date()).getTime();if (a && a.myt && b) {var t = b - a.myt;var bi = a.href.indexOf("&clkt=");if (bi > 0) {var c = a.href.substring(0, bi+6); var d = a.href.substring(bi+6, a.href.length);var ei = d.indexOf("&");var r = '';if (ei >= 0)r = d.substring(ei, d.length);a.href = c + t + r; } else {a.href += "&clkt=" + t;}}return true;}(function(){var e=function(b,a,c){var d="&"+a+"=",a=b.indexOf(d);0>a?c=b+d+c:(a+=d.length,d=b.indexOf("&",a),c=0<=d?b.substring(0,a)+c+b.substring(d):b.substring(0,a)+c);return 2E3<c.length?b:c};var f=null,g=function(b){f=b};document.addEventListener&&document.addEventListener("mousedown",g,!0);window.xy=function(b,a,c){c=c||a;if((b=b||f)&&a&&c){var d=Math.round(b.clientY-c.offsetTop);a.href=e(a.href,"nx",Math.round(b.clientX-c.offsetLeft));a.href=e(a.href,"ny",d)}};})();function cs(){window.status='';} function jcc(a) {pha=document.getElementById(a); nc=pha.href.indexOf('&jca='); if(nc>=1) return; jca=(717)+(6720)-(441); if (a=='aw0') {jca+=(-4392);} else if (a=='aw1') {jca+=(1043);} else if (a=='aw2') {jca+=(2446);} else if (a=='aw3') {jca+=(-4751);} else {jca=0;} phb=pha.href+'&jca='+jca; pha.href=phb;} function st(id) {var a = document.getElementById(id);if (a) {a.myt = (new Date()).getTime();xy(window.event, a);}return true;}function ha(a){  var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nhi=pha.href.indexOf("&nh=");if(nhi < 1) {pha.href+="&nh=1";}su(a); jcc(a); }function ca(a) {  var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nci=pha.href.indexOf("&nc=");if(nci < 1) {pha.href+="&nc=1";}su(a); jcc(a); top.location.href=document.getElementById(a).href;}function ga(o,e) {if (document.getElementById) {a=o.id.substring(1);p="";r="";g=e.target;if (g) {t=g.id;f=g.parentNode;if (f) {p=f.id;h=f.parentNode;if (h)r=h.id;}} else {h=e.srcElement;f=h.parentNode;if (f)p=f.id;t=h.id;}if (t==a||p==a||r==a)return true;var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nbi=pha.href.indexOf("&nb=");if(nbi < 1) {pha.href+="&nb=1";}su(a); jcc(a); top.location.href=document.getElementById(a).href;}}</script>

<a title="www.gfi.com/fax" target="_top" onmouseover="return ss('','aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')" onfocus="ss('','aw0')" onclick="ha('aw0')" id="aw0" href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=BnKD-aMvYT-vyI6qU0AW52p2hB7aAuLECxuLcvRjAjbcBsOMtEAEYASDg8JsKKAQ4AFD85ObkAmCtytiDvAygAYqXwv8DugEKMTIweDYwMF9hc8gBAdoBQWZpbGU6Ly8vQzovRG9jdW1lbnRzJTIwYW5kJTIwU2V0dGluZ3MvTEVGVEVSSVMvRGVza3RvcC9nb29nbGUuaHRtgAIByALW54UYqAMByAMf6AP2COgD5QP1AwAAAMT1AwAAQBA&amp;num=1&amp;sig=AOD64_3Jznh97UCO3fRznTsPK1OHiH354Q&amp;client=ca-pub-7051474033111975&amp;adurl=http://landfax.gfi.com/fax-server-exchange-sm/%3Fadv%3D69%26loc%3D618" class="adt"><span>Send fax from computers</span></a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/url?ct=abg&amp;q=https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/request.py%3Fcontact%3Dabg_afc%26url%3Dfile:///C:/Documents%252520and%252520Settings/LEFTERIS/Desktop/google.htm%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dca-pub-7051474033111975%26adU%3Dwww.gfi.com/fax%26adT%3DSend%2Bfax%2Bfrom%2Bcomputers%26adU%3Dwww.tradestead.com/ElectricGadgets%26adT%3DBuy%2BElectronic%2BGadgets%26adU%3Dwww.cloudsolutions.co.uk%26adT%3DGoogle%2BMigration%2BTool%26adU%3DAllwaySync.com%26adT%3DSkyDrive%2BPC%2Bsync%2Bsoftware%26gl%3DGR&amp;usg=AFQjCNGOinsMYeIWqJU_FmQly3Uc-yRscA"><img height="16" border="0" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/abglogo/adc-en-100c-000000.png" alt="AdChoices"></a>
```

Probably that is what you want...